# Dynamically get mac address of esp32 and use it in ethernet library

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

Can anyone enlighten me on how to get mac address dynamically from esp32 and use it in ethernet library. So far, I have got mac address from wifi library as follows:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
 byte mac[6] = {};    
 void setup(){
   Serial.begin(115200);
   delay(500);
   WiFi.macAddress(mac);
   if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed DHCP"));
    }
}
```

I always end up getting "Failed DHCP" even though my esp32 is connected with the internet. One more problem that I face when storing mac address in separate array is that the hex number "A" is not stored as "0A". Please help me out.

Comment: The API you're using doesn't have a "get last error" function, where you get more information on the error?

Comment: I am sorry, I am unable to understand what you are saying, I have written complete code now.

Comment: When a function returns an error, is there another function you can call to get error information?  There has to be a reason why that function returned `0` -- the system knows why because it was the system that knows something is wrong.  Probably a global variable was set to an error value that you can query.

Comment: You’re not storing anything in the `mac` variable before you use it. Why do you expect it to have any effect?

Comment: 1. Your `mac` array has 0 length. 2. You never assign  a MAC address to the `mac` variable. 3. Are you sure `.begin()` returning 0 is an error state? 4. The Arduino framework automatically connects to the last WiFi network. I doubt getting IP from a different connection, but same MAC will work properly. 5. Why is this tagged [tag:esp8266wifi]?

Comment: the esp32 WiFi library returns the MAC address only as String. look at SDK API for a function which returns the MAC address as bytes

Comment: The code has been further improved if you can understand now, do tell me. @Juraj yes the SDK API was helpful in understanding the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following to get mac address,

```
#include <WiFi.h>

String macAddr = WiFi.macAddress();
```

or use this,

```
String getMacAddress()
{
   uint8_t baseMac[6];

   // Get MAC address for WiFi station
   esp_read_mac(baseMac, ESP_MAC_WIFI_STA);

   char baseMacChr[18] = {0};
   sprintf(baseMacChr, "%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", baseMac[0], baseMac[1], baseMac[2], baseMac[3], baseMac[4], baseMac[5]);

   String macAddress = String(baseMacChr);

   Serial.print("MAC Address :: ");
   Serial.println(macAddress);

   return String(baseMacChr);
}
```

I used this for ESP32-S CAM and works great.

Comment: the '#include <WiFi.h>' should be in the first part, not the second. PS really appreciate this answer

Answer (score 0):

I use it with ethernet library:

```
esp_efuse_mac_get_default(baseMac);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).